# Stop DataGridView from autoadding a new row

Tags: c#, datagridview

Hey guys,
sorry for this probably fairly simple question but I'm starting to get crazy about this^^
Point is I show a little data to the user via an DataGridView, its not bound to a datasource but added directly.
Now so far everything works fine but the dgv always automatically adds a new, empty line after the ones I added. I've tried removing it by rows.remove(), etc but I just got errors...

Maybe one of you knows the answer?

Thanks for any help in advance!!!

Greets,

Lorenz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the [DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows.aspx) property value to *false* to hide the new row. Set it back to `true` to show the new row again.

Comment: Excellent! So simple, yet I didn't think of it^^ thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Lorenz: Dont you know that there are some badges that you can earn by voting a lot :)

Comment: Actually I had a lot more, but I deleted cookies on my working machine and gone was the Stackoverflow access^^